# Is it possible to display selected items in dropdowncheckboxes text area in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application, I have dropdowncheckboxes control in that whatever items I selected I need to show that selected items in  dropdown textfield as separated with comma.

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1mBb.png)

I tried this code but I am not getting result:

.aspx: Using this "DropDownCheckBoxes" control

```
<%@ Register Namespace="Saplin.Controls" Assembly="DropDownCheckBoxes" TagPrefix="asp"%>
         <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="dropdown1" runat="server"   
         UseSelectAllNode="true" UseButtons="true"   
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged"     
         AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="drpdwnstyle"><Style DropDownBoxBoxWidth="200"/>
         </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
```

.CS

```
protected void dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<String> checkedList = new List<string>();
    foreach (ListItem item in dropdown1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            checkedList.Add(item.Text);
        }
        dropdown1.DataTextField = String.Join(",", checkedList);
    }
}
```

I tried so much but I am not getting anything. 
Can anyone please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main issue is that DataTextField is not the property you want to set. This property is used together with data source, to let data bound control know which data source's field should be used as text. There is a similar field for value. Correct property to use is `Texts.SelectBoxCaption`, if I understood your intent correctly.

Also there is no point in assigning this inside foreach, so I moved it out of the loop:

```
foreach (ListItem item in dropdown1.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        checkedList.Add(item.Text);
    }
}

dropdown1.Texts.SelectBoxCaption = String.Join(",", checkedList);
```

Comment: hi Andrei, thank you for u r help can you please tell me if i select large names of items it will not display properly can you please tell me how to do this. thank you

Comment: If i select large names of items or many items i want to  display in caption that all items what i select i need to select items in caption and press arrows is it possible to do this. can you please tell me how to do this. Thank you

Comment: @Shiv, I think it has to do with styling of the control. Check out css applied to this header and see if you can customize it. I have never used this control myself so cannot help much more about this

Answer (score 0):

Small correction, the following line :

```
dropdown1.Texts.SelectBoxCaption = String.Join(",", checkedList);
```

Will be replaced by :

```
dropdown1.Texts.SelectBoxCaption = String.Join(",", checkedList.ToArray());
```